# Xcode Flutter ScaffoldState Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Error

Tags: xcode, flutter, exit-code

I have an error in Xcode.

I've tried version 12.1 and 11.7. The error occurs in both versions. How can you fix this error?

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/getflutter 1.1.3/lib/components/appbar/gf_appbar.dart:311:57:
Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.

final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);

```
                                                ^^^^^^
```

../../../downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1918:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {

```
               ^^
```

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same issue on
 `Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-7.0.pre.43)`
fixed by flutter change channel to stable
 `Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3)`